# Problema con pseudo elemento con Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

estoy utilizando pseudo elemento en CSS

```
.menu-item-has-children::after{
    content: '+';
}
```

Y lo que deseo hacer es por medo de JQUERY es hacer que el signo + dentro del content gire

```
$('.menu-item-has-children::after').css({
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
     transform: rotate(45deg);
})
```

He investigado un poco y lo que encuentro por internet es que los pseudo elementos Jquery no los reconoce.  ¿Como puedo hacer para lograr que pueda girar el signo de + ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías aplicar la rotacion como parte del css.

Notar el `display: inline-block;`. Por defecto `::after` es `inline` y como como tal no se puede transformar

```js
$(".item").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("rotated");
});
```

```css
.item::after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '+';
}
.item.rotated::after {
  transform: rotate(45deg)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="item">item</li>
</ul>
```